# How to create a Django website to post articles?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm new to django and I really have no idea how should I structure a website for the purpose of posting articles (like tutorials).
I'm not asking for specific code, but how does it work?

Should I make a base template and a html file for every single article that I'll post? If so, how should be the folder structure in the project? How can I show a list of all those articles and redirect to them if a user clicks on it? Should I link them to a database entry? How can I do that?

I'm asking those things because I only did things that involved reading content from the database/model and showing it on a template, but articles need images and other special construction that a blog textfield would not be enough.

If it is too confusing, just say so, and I'll try to put in another words, I'm really struggling to put my question into words.

Comment: it seems https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIyxjRJ8VNY would be a good reference to start with. to save time and avoid getting overwhelmed, might as well install Django and run sample code on https://github.com/search?q=django+basics

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just starting with Django, and if that is correct, I suggest you to start by making a hello world app to have a quick grasp of how django works, here is a good [tutorial](https://dev.to/developerroad/create-your-first-django-app-hello-world-app-3k52).

If you aren't just skip that part and  start by writing down the requirements.

If you want your blog articles to have a header image, or a special text field in which you can write rich text, or even if you want to build a categories/tag system, write that in your requirements.

For each thing you would like to have django has already some ways to solve it.

For example for the image of the article you will use a django model field name [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#imagefield).

I'll give you a really basic reference for the article model (You'll have to start a project and create an app).

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
   body = models.TextField()
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/images") 
   created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   
   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

Remember to make use of views and template language, but if you need some help with the image in the template just use this:

```html
{% if post.image %}
<img src="{{ post.image.url }}" title="Post image">
{% endif %}
```

Also you have to realize that you'll need a hosting service like heroku or amazon for your app, and a media CDN  to host the images of your posts. If you decide to use heroku i recommend to use Cloudinary and [here is a tutorial](https://developerroad.herokuapp.com/blog/article/10/).

If you need some inspiration feel free to checkout [my blog](https://developerroad.herokuapp.com/blog/?filter=liked).

Comment: Thanks a lot, and your blog is pretty cool (your article structure is pretty similar to what I had in mind actually), but I do have a sequence to my questions, if your article is made of fields in django models, how can it has a lot of images in between paragraphs? That's actually what I'm struggling to imagine doing with django, and the only way I can imagine it, is by making a template for every single article... Or is this possible with rich text?

Comment: For sure it's not a simple django field. There are some extensions available to have Rich text editors as Django fields. [Ckeditor](pip install django-ckeditor) or rich text editor[](https://pypi.org/project/django-richtexteditor/)